# Parsing user expression for formatting errors

Tags: python, regex, parsing

User provides a string containing a Python expression : `"a==(1,1) and {b==2 or c==foo}"`.

I am trying to write a parser that checks the following rules:

1. There needs to be a whitespace before and after a logical expression (`or` or `and`)
2. There needs to be a whitespace before and after curly braces
3. There should be NO whitespace within an expression (`a ==(1,1)` is invalid)

I found that "parser" module but I am not sure I understand it.

Establishing all the rules through multiple regular expressions (reading the string char by char and making sure if satisfies the rules) is very tedious.

What is the most elegant way to tackle this problem?

Comment: In Perl it would look somehow like this /^(((([\w\d]+)|\((?4)(,(?4))+\))==(?3))|(\{(?1)\} (and|or) \{(?1)\}))$/ i guess(not tested). I don't know if python support such expressions.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with what Python would consider "Syntax Errors" so I retitled your question (and cleaned it up a bit). If you actually _do_ want to check syntax rather than formatting, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @ agf: Yes, I should have mentioned formatting errors rather than "
syntax error". Thanks for correcting that.

Comment: May the used provided string contain any Python expression, or just a subset similar to the example above? May identifiers be just single characters, or also something like "candy" or "work"?

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way I'd say is to use something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), a real parser combined with "pythonic" ease of use.

It may be a bit of overkill for small projects, but it isn't too hard to get started and will allow for plenty of growth in the syntax.  Software requirements always seem to grow in one direction so I'd recommend giving it a try.